# Suma de campos para graficar

Tags: php, php5, gráficas

realizo un sistema que básicamente son tickets de trabajo con lo cual uno de los principales objetivos es medir cuantos casos según prioridad se atienden (baja, media o alta), mi BD esta diseñada con llaves foráneas por lo cual necesito que al graficar me muestre la suma de esas lineas con esa priodidad es decir, que sume todos los que tenga la prioridad 1, 2 o 3.

Mi sistema ya grafica pero el problema que tengo es que no suma según la prioridad solo muestra todas las lenas y el titulo de la linea, por que no se como realizar esa suma y que me muestre lo que necesito es decir que sume y que muestra la grafica (alta, media y baja).

Así esta diseñada mi tabla central **ticket** , espero en verdad me puedan ayudar.

```
id              PK
title
description
process_1   
process_2   
updated_at  
created_at  
kind_id         FK  
user_id         FK  
asigned_id  
project_id      FK
category_id     FK
priority_id     FK
turn_id         FK
area_id         FK
status_id       FK
```

Mi tabla foránea **priority**

```
id      PK  
name
```

Aquí esta el código de mi gráfica

**Aquí selecciona la tabla y mesta los registros con los títulos según el campo que yo selecciono   "title"**

```html
 <?php 
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from ticket order by priority_id desc");
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       ?>
  
  
  ['<?php echo $res['title']   ?>'],
  
  
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Aquí es donde selecciona por el campo priority_id, **aqui es donde necesito que haga la suma sobre ese campo es decir si hay varios "1" que los sume y lo asigne a "alta" ya que es en mi llave foránea alta=1**

```
<?php 

               $sql=mysql_query("SELECT priority_id, COUNT(*) total FROM ticket GROUP BY priority_id");
                  while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                  ?>



                  [<?php echo $res['total']?> ],




                <?php
                }             
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso más que sumar entiendo que se trata de contar cuantos ticket hay con cada una de las prioridades.

En estos caso te puedes apoyar en las cláusulas `COUNT` y `GROUP BY` de SQL.

COUNT, cuenta el número total de registro, ejemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket;
```

GROUP BY, agrupa los datos iguales por una o mas columnas, ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket GROUP BY priority_id;
```

Utilizando ambas podemos contar el número de registros de cada agrupación,  o lo que es lo mismo, contar el número de registros iguales por una columna dada. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT priority_id, COUNT(*) total
FROM ticket
GROUP BY priority_id;
```

Con esto conseguimos el resultado que esperas, saber el total de registros de cada una de la prioridades.

Si quieres ademas obtener los nombres por la clave foranea, puedes agregar un INNER JOIN, ejemplo:

```
SELECT t.priority_id, p.name, COUNT(*) total
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN priority p ON t.priority_id = p.id
GROUP BY t.priority_id, p.name;
```

---

Aparte de lo indicado, hacerte saber que la extensión mysql_* de php esta obsoleta y fue eliminada en la versión PHP7, por lo que su uso está totalmente desaconsejado, en su lugar debería utilizarse MySQLi o PDO.

Comment: es lo que necesito solo que tengo un problema, al realizar la consulta directamente en mi SQL si me muestra el total por cada uno de las prioridades que hay registradas, pero al realizarlo en el código me grafica las prioridades es decir 1,2 y 3 que están mi tablas mas no me muestra el total de las prioridades no se si me explique

Comment: @Carlos Tienes que acceder a la columna por el alias que le dimos es decir, `$res['total']` para recuperar el dato

Comment: Si muchas gracias tienes razón, salio perfecto

Comment: solo una consulta mas para acceder a las descripciones que se encuentran en mis tablas foráneas lo puedo hacer por un left join?

Comment: @Carlos Si necesitas obtener todos los ticket y sus descripciones deberas hacer una nueva consulta. Si lo que quieres es obtener el nombre de la prioridad que esta en otra tabla puedes agregar un `INNER JOIN` sin problema, para obtenerlos en la misma consulta del COUNT.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo haré por medio de INNER JOIN ... Saludos

Comment: @Carlos Te edite la respuesta añadiendo el ejemplo con el `INNER JOIN`

Comment: ya actualice el código de mi pregunta es decir lo que me proporcionaste ya cuenta cuantos tickets por prioridad tengo (segunda parte de código de la pregunta) ahora solo con el INNER JOIN tengo que obtener el nombre de la prioridad de mi tabla foranea (primera parte del codigo de la pregunta) pero si coloco el INNER JOIN no muestra nada

Comment: @Carlos Viste que edite la pregunta y te mostre un ejemplo de como debe quedar la consulta? Lo probaste?

Comment: Una disculpa no me di cuanta que la editaste, la modifique con lo que tengo actualmente, me puede volver a editarla por favor. Probe con el INNER JOIN en donde se cuantas las prioridades pero no hace nada sin embarlo lo hago en SQL y si me toma las descripciones

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79018/discussion-between-xerif-and-carlos).